# Excel - Add randomly generated line (composed of 4 columns) at the end of a static line

Tags: excel

I have an xlsx file with 2 worksheets tabs.

In the first one, I have the following content : [first worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAy4D.png)

In the second one, I have the following content : [second worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcXGU.png)

I would like to add the content of each line from the first worksheet at the end of each line of the second worksheet IF the number randomly generated is the same.

Do you know a way to achieve this ?

Thanks for your time,

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it worked:

[Formula for Category column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/um71y.png)

[Formula for Description column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rzS7.png)

Same process for Description, and Resolution Code by replacing the last column index (A$, B$, C$, D$, etc.).

Result: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jjYQ.png)

I wanted to know if there is an easier way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, this formula should work if you first paste it to cell D2 on second worksheet, and then copy and paste it to all the range D2:G11 or below, assuming that worksheet names are Sheet1 and Sheet2.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(Sheet2!$C2,Sheet1!$E:$E,0)),"")
```